# reduce spacing above fraction bar in display mode

Tags: spacing

I have the following code:

```
$$
\begin{Large}
\textbf{Volume = } \bm{{\dfrac{nhs^2}{12}}\Bigl(\!\csc\bigl({\tfrac{\pi}{n}}\bigr) + 2\cot\bigl({\tfrac{\pi}{n}}\bigr)\!\Bigr)}
\end{Large}
$$
```

Which generates:

[image]

Which is what I want except for the excessive vertical space between nh$s^2$ and the fraction bar.  Does anyone know how to reduce this?  Using \frac instead of \dfrac didn't help and I don't want to shrink the whole fraction by using \tfrac.

Comment: Is `nhs` the name of a variable, or does it denote the product of the variables `n`, `h`, and `s`? Please advise.

Comment: you should not use `$$` in latex and you definitely should never use a size command such as `\Large` in math mode (LaTeX will have warned about this).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Belated congratulations on passing the 750k rep point mark!

Comment: Please enlighten us to why `\Large` and `\bm` would appear to be important to you for the formula at hand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to move the numerator nearer to the fraction line: consider

```
\frac{nhs}{10}+\frac{g}{2}
```

that I'll represent in two ways, the one you're asking for and the standard one

[image]

Do you see the problem? The height of the numerators are inconsistent. Having a single fraction in the formula is irrelevant, in my opinion.

You can achieve the reduced spacing with

```
\frac{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{$\displaystyle nhs^2$}}{12}
```

if you really want to, but I'd not do it. And I'd probably follow Mico's suggestion to do

```
\frac{1}{12}nhs^2
```

Second problem with your code. You want to emphasize your equation, but is there any reason to use `\Large` size and boldface? Your equation is already displayed, this is sufficient to emphasize its importance. *Maybe* (but I'd not do it) boldface, but definitely not `\Large`. Anyway, none of the methods Mico suggest is good, I'm afraid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\newenvironment{vardisplay}[1]{%
  % #1 contains the settings to apply
  $$% start a display
  \hspace{0pt}\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{minipage}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}$$\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Volume} =
  \frac{nhs^2}{12}
  \bigl(\csc\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr) + 2\cot\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr)\bigr)
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{vardisplay}{\boldmath}
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Volume} =
  \frac{nhs^2}{12}
  \bigl(\csc\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr) + 2\cot\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr)\bigr)
\end{equation*}
\end{vardisplay}
\lipsum[3][1-5]
\begin{vardisplay}{\boldmath\Large}
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Volume} =
  \frac{nhs^2}{12}
  \bigl(\csc\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr) + 2\cot\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr)\bigr)
\end{equation*}
\end{vardisplay}
\lipsum[4][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seeing the formula in context and compared to the other realizations should convince you that the first one is better.

The same but with

```
\frac{1}{12}nhs^2
```

[image]

Comment: The \raisebox worked - thank you!

Comment: @Nate The main purpose of my answer was to tell you *not* to use it. 

Answer (score 2):

The following screenshot features three equations: (i) the OP's original version; (ii) a version that cleans up the OP's code (e.g., by getting rid of a number of unneeded pairs of curly braces) and uses `\tfrac{1}{12} nhs^2` in place of `\dfrac{nhs^2}{12}` to achieve the OP's stated formatting objective; and (iii) a version of (ii) that employs normal-weight math, as I don't understand the purpose of **bold-facing** the entire formula. "For when everything is bold, nothing is bold..."

Aside: Please don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document. Instead, use `\[` and `\]` to initiate and terminate an unnumbered displayed math group. For a longer discussion of this issue, please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) Finally, do note that `\Large` is a text-mode command; its use inside math mode can have unpredictable results.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

$$
\begin{Large}
\textbf{Volume = } \bm{{\dfrac{nhs^2}{12}}\Bigl(\!\csc\bigl({\tfrac{\pi}{n}}\bigr) + 2\cot\bigl({\tfrac{\pi}{n}}\bigr)\!\Bigr)}
\end{Large}
$$

\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\Large
\boldmath % <-- use \boldmath *before* entering math
\[
\textbf{Volume} = 
  \tfrac{1}{12}\, nhs^2
  \bigl( 
         \csc\tfrac{\pi}{n} 
      + 2\cot\tfrac{\pi}{n}
  \bigr) 
\]
\endgroup

\begingroup
\Large
\[
\mathrm{Volume} = 
  \tfrac{1}{12}\, nhs^2
  \bigl(
         \csc\tfrac{\pi}{n} 
      + 2\cot\tfrac{\pi}{n}
  \bigr)
\]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```